# two greenplum installation on the same machine

Tags: greenplum

I have an old version of greenplum and I would like to upgrade to version  5.0.0 since it has been released. https://github.com/greenplum-db/gpdb/releases/tag/5.0.0.

I have a huge machine, and I can not simply have an equivalent one. So I would like to know how can I run both version on the same machine. I have seen for example gpseginstall distribute binaries to the /usr/local/gpdb which is already there for the old version.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I have run multiple versions in parallel on a single node system.

You need to set your config file you use for the gpinitsystem  for different segment/mirror directories, master port, starting port, etc..

You will also need two different OS profiles to source, so when you log as gpadmin you can source your 4.3 or 5.0 paths ($GPHOME, $MASTER_DATA_DIRECTORY) for gpstart, gpstop, psql, etc..

Hope this makes sense... I haven't tried it on a multi node system, but the setup should be the same

i.e.

**GPDB 4.3**

```
ARRAY_NAME="GPDB"

MACHINE_LIST_FILE=./hostsfile

SEG_PREFIX=seg

PORT_BASE=40000

declare -a DATA_DIRECTORY=(/gpsegment4 /gpsegment4 /gpsegment4 /gpsegment4)

MASTER_HOSTNAME=mdw

MASTER_DIRECTORY=/gpmaster4

MASTER_PORT=5432

TRUSTED_SHELL=ssh

CHECK_POINT_SEGMENTS=8

ENCODING=UNICODE

DATABASE_NAME=gpadmin

#MIRROR_PORT_BASE=50000

REPLICATION_PORT_BASE=41000

#MIRROR_REPLICATION_PORT_BASE=51000

#declare -a MIRROR_DATA_DIRECTORY=(/mirror4 /mirror4 /mirror4 /mirror4)
```

**GPDB 5.0**

```
ARRAY_NAME="GPDB"

MACHINE_LIST_FILE=./hostsfile

SEG_PREFIX=seg

PORT_BASE=60000

declare -a DATA_DIRECTORY=(/gpsegment5 /gpsegment5 /gpsegment5 /gpsegment5)

MASTER_HOSTNAME=mdw

MASTER_DIRECTORY=/gpmaster5

MASTER_PORT=7432

TRUSTED_SHELL=ssh

CHECK_POINT_SEGMENTS=8

ENCODING=UNICODE

DATABASE_NAME=gpadmin

#MIRROR_PORT_BASE=70000

REPLICATION_PORT_BASE=61000

#MIRROR_REPLICATION_PORT_BASE=71000

#declare -a MIRROR_DATA_DIRECTORY=(/mirror5 /mirror5 /mirror5 /mirror5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen where you can have different versions installed, then change the greenplum-db link to point to the one you want to run.  That link is referenced when you enter gpstart.  Not sure how you could have two different versions running at the same time on the same machine.

If your goal is to do upgrade dry runs and test on the new release, another alternative could be to deploy a Greenplum cluster using Microsoft Azure.  This would deploy the latest version (5.0).

Sounds like you know how to build your own greenplum so you could delete that 5.0 install then install the version you are currently using, then practice the upgrade/migration as well as just kick the tires of 5.0.

You could also easily have side by side systems in Azure; one running your current release and the other running 5.0.

The smallest cluster you can deploy is 1 master and 1 segment which could be adequate depending on your requirements.

Hope this helps

Comment: The "greenplum-db" link is just a shortcut to the currently running version, and makes life easier if you only have one version up and running at any time. If you specify the full path instead of the shortcut, it will just work fine. Also if you want to run (not just install) two versions in parallel, you need to change all the ports and directories, as pointed out by @oak.

Comment: Depending on your objective, and how your current Greenplum database is being used (especially if its production) its advisable to make certain you have a current full backup of your database prior to attempting the parallel install.

Comment: Why that? Besides the recommendation to have a backup anyway?

Comment: Hi A. Scherbaum.  The suggestion here is to install a new database instance on a server hosting an existing database instance.  That's a significant modification to that server.  Specifically in this case, is to install a second instance of the same database product.  I don't think Pivotal officially supports two instances of Greenplum on the same host.  If that server is being used in production.

Comment: Well I hit enter too soon - sorry......  if that server is being used in production, the least I'd do is make certain I have a good backup.  But if at all possible, again if its prod, I'd stay entirely away from that server to perform any experimentation on.   But that's just how I'd approach it.

Comment: If it's a prod environment, there is yet another reason not to run two instances on the same hardware: each instance will try to grab as many resources as possible, memory, CPU, network and such. The resource management coming with GPDB can only control the same instance, and has no idea about other instances on the same hardware. The result will be disappointing ...

Comment: Video showing how to install Greenplum using Microsoft Azure      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JrN97OJgrDw